# Normal Distribution With Many Zero Values

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

I have here a probability density function representing the amount of hours spent studying for a class final. Unsurprisingly, many of the students do not study for the final.

[image]

However, because so many students stack up on 0 hours studied, it appears that the curve extends into a negative domain, which is not possible because you can't study for negative hours.

Here are some questions:

- How can one interpret the results for a curve like this?
- Can values for probability, z-score, std, cdf, etc be reliably calculated?
- Is there a way to transform this so that all values of the domain are greater than 0?

Comment: this isn't one of your questions, but you might find it interesting to look at zero inflated models, like maybe a zero inflated gamma. And I'm sure this isn't what you mean, but adding $1$ to every data point makes all values greater than 0... i suspect you really want to make it so you can apply standard normal-theory analyses?

Comment: Your curve contradicts your characterization of the data: there is no "stack" of zero hours.  Indeed, because the curve is continuously drawn and has unit area, it appears you intend us to interpret it as a *density* function.  As such, it assigns *zero* probability to the value $0.$

Comment: @whuber so in short you are saying that the area under this curve will still be equal to 1? I'm going to have to check this when I get the chance.

Comment: @tear728 did you check this?  A quick estimation (curve pretty much bisects a 60x0.030 bounding box, (60*0.03)/2 = 0.9 ~1) would suggest that it is likely true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be better off treating this as a mixture of two distributions rather than trying to apply the standard normal-theory tools, so instead I'm going to outline a bit about the zero inflated Gamma distribution, including computing its first two moments, to give you a sense of how this goes. You could pretty easily swap the Gamma out for a different continuous distribution if you'd like (e.g. a Beta distribution scaled to be in $[0,100]$). Happy to add updates later if this is not helpful.

Let $Z_1,\dots,Z_n\stackrel{\text{iid}}\sim\text{Bern}(\theta)$ and consider  $X_1,\dots,X_n$ where
$$
X_i \vert Z_i \stackrel{\text{iid}}\sim \begin{cases}\Gamma(\alpha, \beta) & Z_i = 1 \\ 0 & Z_i = 0\end{cases}
$$

so each $X_i$ is a mixture of a point mass at $0$ with probability $1-\theta$ and a $\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ with probability $\theta$. We interpret this as $Z_i$ being a hidden latent variable that determines whether or not the student studies, and then $X_i$ is the observed value.

This is a bit formal but I'm going to mention it for the sake of completeness. $X_i$ does not have a pdf in the usual sense because it's neither discrete nor continuous, but if we consider the measure $\nu = \lambda + \delta_0$, i.e. the Lebesgue measure plus a point mass at $0$, then $\nu(A) = 0 \implies P_X(A) = 0$ for any measurable $A$ so we can get a pdf $f_X := \frac{\text dP_X}{\text d\nu}$ w.r.t. $\nu$.

But what does this pdf look like? We can work out the CDF $F$ using some rules of conditional probability.
$$
F(x) = P(X\leq x \cap Z = 0) + P(X\leq x \cap Z = 1) \\
= P(X\leq x | Z = 0)P(Z=0) + P(X\leq x | Z=1)P(Z=1) \\
= 1 \cdot (1 - \theta) + F_\Gamma(x; \alpha, \beta) \theta \\
= 1 - \theta + \theta F_\Gamma(x; \alpha, \beta)
$$
where $F_\Gamma$ denotes the CDF of an actual Gamma distribution.

So we want a function $f_X$ such that
$$
F(x) = \int_{[0, x]} f_X\,\text d\nu.
$$
Note that
$$
\int_{[0, x]} f_X\,\text d\nu = \int_{\{0\}} f_X\,\text d\delta_0 + \int_{(0, x)} f_X\,\text d\lambda \\
= f_X(0) + \int_{(0, x)} f_X\,\text d\lambda
$$
so I can take 
$$
f_X(x) = 1 - \theta + \theta f_\Gamma(x; \alpha, \beta).
$$

Let's check that this is a valid pdf:
$$
\int_{[0,\infty)} f_X\,\text d\nu = 1 - \theta + \theta \int_0^\infty f_\Gamma \,\text d\lambda = 1
$$
so this is indeed a valid pdf (w.r.t. $\nu$).

---

Now I'll work out the first two moments of $X_i$.

$$
E(X_i) = \int_{[0,\infty)} x f_X(x)\,\text d\nu(x) \\
= 0 \cdot \int_{\{0\}} f_X\,\text d\delta_0 + \int_{(0,\infty)} x f_X(x)\,\text d\lambda(x) \\
= 0 + \theta \int_0^\infty x f_\Gamma(x) \,\text d\lambda(x)
= \frac{\theta\alpha}\beta := \mu < \infty. 
$$
Next
$$
E(X_i^2) =  \int_{[0,\infty)} x^2 f_X(x)\,\text d\nu(x) \\
= 0 + \theta \int_0^\infty x^2 f_\Gamma(x)\,\text d\lambda(x) \\
= \frac{\theta\alpha(1 + \alpha)}{\beta^2}.
$$
This means
$$
\sigma^2 := E(X_i^2) - \mu^2 < \infty.
$$

At long last I have confirmed the following facts: we have a collection of iid RVs $X_1, X_2,\dots$ with finite means and variances, so we can happily apply the standard CLT to conclude

$$
\frac{\bar X_n - \mu_n}{\sqrt n} \stackrel{\text d}\to \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2).
$$

Now as for how good this is, you'll probably want to do some simulations. Also I'm not saying this is actually a good model.

---

I'll check my math with the following simulation:

```
theta <- .76
a <- 5.4
b <- 1.2
n <- 1e6

set.seed(42)
z <- rbinom(n, 1, theta)
x <- numeric(n)
x[z==1] <- rgamma(sum(z), shape=a, rate=b)

hist(x, main="Zero inflated Gamma simulations")

mean(x)
theta * a / b  # agrees

mean(x^2)
theta * a * (1 + a) / b^2  # agrees
```

[image]

Also note that I'm not using a KDE to show the distribution like (it looks like) you are. Those typically aren't appropriate for distributions that have a point mass like this. Plus if you're using one that puts a mini gaussian at each data point then it's implicitly assumed that the support is all of $\mathbb R$ so you can also get positive probability on impossible areas like you did.

If you choose to use this model and want to estimate the parameters, the [EM algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) is the usual way to go.

In this case though there's no doubt as to which class a particular $X_i$ belongs as if $X_i = 0$ then $Z_i = 0$ almost surely. So you can do

```
mean(x > 0)  # compare with theta

mu.x <- mean(x[x > 0])
s2.x <- var(x[x > 0])
(b.hat <- mu.x / s2.x)
(a.hat <- mu.x^2 / s2.x)
```

and these agree. But I have a massive sample size and $\theta$ isn't particularly close to $0$ or $1$ here so it's not impressive to be so accurate with this conditional approach.